# Can't access Internet on one PC in my Network

Tags: networking, network-manager, internet

I have two PCs that are connected via Ethernet in a local network. Let's call them A and B. A is connected via Wi-Fi to a router as well. Then I have machine C that is connected to the router. At A ipv4 forwarding is enabled and I can successfully access B via A via C. All machines have static IPs.

[Network Setup Figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0lL3Q.jpg)

These commands do work:

```
c $ ssh a@A
a $ ping b
   64 bytes ...
a $ ssh b@B
```

I also added routes so that I can access and ping C from A directly.

```
c $ ssh b@B
a $ ping B
  64 bytes ...
```

This does work perfectly. BUT I can not access the Internet from machine A anymore. There is a route from A to the router. I run the network via /etc/network/interfaces. It worked before I set up machine B and I did not change the interfaces file for the wlan0 instance.

From Machine A:

$ route

```
Destination     Router          Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         192.168.20.154  0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan0
20.0.0.0        *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
192.168.21.0    *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wlan0
```

$ ifconfig

```
    eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  Hardware Adresse 70:8b:cd:4d:ea:1f  
          inet Adresse:20.0.0.1  Bcast:20.0.0.255  Maske:255.255.255.0
          inet6-Adresse: fe80::728b:cdff:fe4d:ea1f/64 Gültigkeitsbereich:Verbindung
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metrik:1
          RX-Pakete:244312 Fehler:0 Verloren:0 Überläufe:0 Fenster:0
          TX-Pakete:260977 Fehler:0 Verloren:0 Überläufe:0 Träger:0
          Kollisionen:0 Sendewarteschlangenlänge:1000 
          RX-Bytes:21781502 (21.7 MB)  TX-Bytes:156504678 (156.5 MB)
          Interrupt:16 Speicher:f7200000-f7220000 

lo        Link encap:Lokale Schleife  
          inet Adresse:127.0.0.1  Maske:255.0.0.0
          inet6-Adresse: ::1/128 Gültigkeitsbereich:Maschine
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metrik:1
          RX-Pakete:341965 Fehler:0 Verloren:0 Überläufe:0 Fenster:0
          TX-Pakete:341965 Fehler:0 Verloren:0 Überläufe:0 Träger:0
          Kollisionen:0 Sendewarteschlangenlänge:1 
          RX-Bytes:183045343 (183.0 MB)  TX-Bytes:183045343 (183.0 MB)


wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  Hardware Adresse 18:cf:5e:81:71:35  
          inet Adresse:xxx.xxx.21.80  Bcast:xxx.xxx.21.255  Maske:255.255.255.0
          inet6-Adresse: fe80::1acf:5eff:fe81:7135/64 Gültigkeitsbereich:Verbindung
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metrik:1
          RX-Pakete:10064 Fehler:0 Verloren:0 Überläufe:0 Fenster:0
          TX-Pakete:7524 Fehler:0 Verloren:0 Überläufe:0 Träger:0
          Kollisionen:0 Sendewarteschlangenlänge:1000 
          RX-Bytes:1064590 (1.0 MB)  TX-Bytes:1690152 (1.6 MB)
```

I can't get out of my network. I can ping machines in the Wi-Fi (wlan0) and eth (eth0) network but I can't access the internet from A.

```
$ ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.

$ ping google.de  /// shows no response at all
```

I appreciate any help as I can't figure out what's the problem.

Comment: Why on earth have you used IP's in the 20.0.0.0 range? In most residential setups you'd need NAT, and not only IP forwarding. Also - please do not censor IP's. They're probably private addresses anyway, and doesn't reveal anything. It makes following what you actually have nigh impossible.

Comment: You are right. Sorry for that I edited my question to include the IPs. Is there something wrong with the 20.0.0.0 range? I use this setup to connect two PCs from a robot and only one of it has WI-FI (Machine A) with a normal desktop PC. As I mentioned I can access the internet from other machines in the same network (192.20.x.x) and NAT is enabled.

Answer (score 1):

The default gateway on A is not in your network. You are using 192.168.21.x/24, but your gateway is 192.168.20.154, which is not in the same network segment.

Besides that, as vidarlo states in the comments, it is very strange that you use 20.0.0.0/24, since that block is part of the public ip space. There are reserved blocks you can use called private ip space.

[Private network on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network)